# how to resolve WebDriver and ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type even if i added the selenium jar files

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

how to resolve webdriver and chromedriver cannot be resolved to a type even if I added the selenium jar files

I have tried all the steps including adding the selenium jar files, I am still getting an error as webdriver and chrome Driver cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.